# Dynamically Defining a Dummy Decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am using a nice tool called https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler

To use it, you need to put a decorator `@profile` at multiple places in the script to indicate which functions should be profiled. Then you execute the script via
`kernprof -l script_to_profile.py`

Obviously, when running the script by itself via `python script_to_profile.py`, the decorator is not defined and hence the script crashes.

I know how to define an identity decorator and I can pass a flag from the command line and define it in the main script depending on how the flag is set. However, I don't know how to pass the decorator definition (or the flag) to modules I load so they don't crash at the moment they are loaded. Any ideas?

```
def profile(func):
        return func
```

Comment: Seems like you could write code that checks of there's a function named `profile` defined, and if not, define it to be the identity decorator.

Comment: Yes, I assume that would work quite nicely! Do you have a pointer to how to query whether a decorator is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way would be to check if something named `profile` exists, and if it doesn't, then define it to be your identity decorator. Something like this.

```
try:
    profile
except NameError:
    def profile(func):
        return func
```

You could go a little further and make sure it's something callable — probably not necessary:

```
import typing

try:
    profile
except NameError:
    profile = None

if not isinstance(profile, typing.Callable):
    def profile(func):
        return func
```

Comment: I tested this with the line profiler and it works! Thank you!